# WiFi Direct on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone, wifi, windows-phone-8.1, wifi-direct

Is it possible to use WiFi Direct to connect to another device (Raspberry Pi) without tapping (NFC)?
The app needs to be able to find all WiFi Direct devices (Raspberry Pi's) in its vicinity, and by tapping one a connection is made to send strings.

The app needs to be able to detect new devices, that have never been paired with the phone before.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone doesn't support WiFi direct communication from the SDK. Although it is available in Windows 8, its not yet present in phones.

According to Channel 9, MSDN

> Windows 8 natively supports Wi-Fi Direct and has integrated the technology into the Windows 8 Play To and proximity sharing experiences.

However this doesn't apply for windows phone.

Answer (score 1):

There are apps on the store which supports it, but I have no idea how to implement that in programming. Take a look at the process of using those apps
http://www.lumiamine.com/2014/07/wifi-direct-on-windows-phone.html